# Angular filter using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

if you take a look at the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ilNYwiTwJIwe5HwteErz?p=preview

```
<select ng-model="query.type">
<li ng-repeat="tech in techs | filter : query">
```

I have a doubt- how in ng-model & the filter expression the 'query' thing (for lack of a better understanding) gets the type field. What exactly is the 'query' thing. Can we console it? And how is the association of query.type<---->query formed.

I do perfectly follow the logical inference of the semantic declaration of the code like-

```
<div ng-repeat="tech in techs | filter: { type : 'mvc' }">
```

which hits the head quire nicely. Any careful explanation on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to understand that `type` is a `String`.

If you want to see what is the `query` - you can add `ng-change` to your `select`, like this:

```
<select ng-model="query.type" ng-change="consoleQuery()">
```

And in controller:

```
 $scope.consoleQuery = function () {
   console.log($scope.query);
 }
```

So now after choose some value from `select` you will see in console that `query` is an `Object`:
`Object {type: "mvp"}`

So when you use in `ng-repeat` `query` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="tech in techs | filter : query">
```

it means the same if you will type the next (see also `Demo`):

```
<li ng-repeat="tech in techs | filter : {type : query.type}">
```

In the last code you will create an `Object` which has property `type` and its value will be `query.type`. But as far as `query` is an `Object` which contain only 1 property `type` - we can use it in the `ng-repeat`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8poVKiFWuOjiNFO485Xy?p=preview

Hope, this will wxplain for you what is going on.

Comment: thanks, i can see now that the the 'query' thing becomes an object when i have query.type and plain string when i have only query.

Answer (score 0):

If you print filter expression like this:

```
<select ng-model="query.type"> {{query}}
```

you will see that `query` is just a normal javascript object:

```
{type: 'mvc'}
```

So when you use filter like `ng-repeat="tech in techs | filter : query` you basically provide a *variable*, which is an object with properties to filter by.

Comment: In other words, query is a variable attached to the scope, which is modified via the ng-modal on the select.

Comment: Yes, this is just some scope variable.

Comment: dsfq - i couldn't print the expression you have mentioned, can you please share the code or plunkr.
Also my question was more targeted to the relationship between query(in ng-repeat) and query.type(in ng-model). Also between query & tech.And most importantly How?